# Database Function - Haskell beginner needing help!

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and am trying to teach myself the language from the Addison-Wesley book - The Craft of Functional Programming.

I'm stuck on one of the exercises and wondered if someone might be able to help:

I need to define a function

```
borrowed :: Database -> Book -> Bool
```

over a library database that can check whether a book in the database has been borrowed and then return True if it has and False if it has not. It might be a really simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out! Any help would be great

Cheers

P

Comment: Can you give us some information about the `Database` type?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, It is simply defined type Database = [(Person, Book)]

Comment: Thanks! If nobody has had a go at this question by the time I get home, I'll answer it then (leaving work now). Have fun with Haskell!

Comment: How is `Person` defined? Does a books presence in the database (and thereby its association with a `Person`) indicate that is is borrowed? Or is there a special `Person`, something like `None`, that indicates that the books i available?

Comment: If `Database` were defined as `[(Book,Person)]` then the standard `lookup` would return `Nothing` if the book is not out; `Just arthur` if Arthur has it out: `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b` (note the other versions of `lookup` on Hoogle for more sophisticated types than `[(a,b)]`.) With the `[(Person,Book)]` order, to use `lookup` you'd have to do `borrowed db book = lookup book ( map (\(x,y) -> (y,x)) db)` This could be made a boolean test easily enough, but why bother matching on `False` and `True` when you can match on `Nothing` and `Just _`?

Answer (score 3):

You just want to see if Book appears anywhere in the list. The simple way to look at this is via induction on the list of books. When there's one book loaned out, you want to compare that,

```
borrowed [(loan_to, loan_book)] key = loan_book == key
```

Then, when you're looking through more books, you want to check if your key is among any of them,

```
borrowed [] key = False
borrowed ((loan_to, loan_book):loans) key = key == loan_book || borrowed loans key
```

When you learn some standard library functions, you can clean it up to something like,

```
borrowed loans key = any ((==key) . snd) loans
```

Comment: +1 for showing the naive recursive solution before pointing to library functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the database is a list of pairs of a person and a book that person has checked out.

```
import Data.List (find)
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

whoBorrowed :: Database -> Book -> Maybe Person
whoBorrowed database book = fmap fst $ find ((== book) . snd) database

borrowed :: Database -> Book -> Bool
borrowed database book = isJust $ whoBorrowed database book
```

Do you understand what all that means, or would you like me to expand on it for you?

Edits:

- Removed use of `<$>` from Control.Applicative; replaced with `fmap`. They mean exactly the same thing.
- Removed use of `second` from Control.Arrow; replaced with `. snd`. Actually, my use of `second` was a bug, fixed now.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for answering that. Is there anyway you could do it without using the imports for Applicative and Arrow? Its just I haven't learnt this yet and its throwing me a bit lol!

Comment: Also, I have defined a Book function as follows - is there anyway you could recommend that is similar to how this is defined? books :: Database -> Person -> [Book]
books db searchPerson
 = [ bookName | (personName, bookName) <- db , personName==searchPerson ]

Comment: @user832488 1. See my edit. 2. Sorry, I'm not sure what you want me to recommend. Your definition of `books` looks fine. Perhaps edit your question to include this new criterion?

Comment: Thanks Dave, sorry if I confused you a bit there. You've been really helpful and I understand a lot better now what needs to be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `any` function was defined just for this purpose!

```
borrowed db book = any (\(person, book') -> book' == book) db
```

Of course, this easy-to-read definition can be mangled in any number of ways. For example, some might prefer this form:

```
borrowed db book = any ((book==) . snd) db
```